# Rails Query - how to compare the months of two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I know rails support between query.

[Example]
Performance (have a start_date, end_date)

I want to bring in the performances by month.

```
First performance (2017.07.01~ 2017.08.31)

Second performance (2017.08.08~ 2017.08.20)

Third performace (2017.08.09~ 2018.08.09)
```

I wanna just get 2017. 08 performances..

Rails Query - how to compare the months of two dates?

I think

```
@performances = Performance.where("? BETWEEN start_date(* change month?) AND end_date(* change month?)", @filter_date(* "2017-08 DATE").month)
```

**UPDATED**

```
  beginning_of_month = @filter_date.beginning_of_month
  end_of_month = @filter_date.end_of_month
  @performances = @performances.where("(start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (start_date < ? AND end_date > ?)", beginning_of_month, end_of_month, beginning_of_month, end_of_month, beginning_of_month, end_of_month)
```

Comment: Use `beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month`

Comment: I know beginning and end of month method, Are you said "2017-08-01 .. 2017-08-31 between start date and end date" ? that is multiple queries :(

Comment: greater than beginning_of_month and less than end_of_month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know Rails Query, but how about this way?

```
(start_date between 2017.08.01 and 2017.08.31) or
(end_date between 2017.08.01 and 2017.08.31) or
(start_date < 2017.08.01 and end_date > 2017.08.31)
```